# What is the Purpose of Office vs Office Location in SP2013 UserProfiles

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

The `Office` profile property gets populated by `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` from AD. So what is the purpose of the `Office Location` Property?

Bismarck

Answer (score 1):

Office location is being user to get the location of the office i.e USA, UK, West campus etc.As this property is set the location using the term set.

I think this property being used when a company having office in different locations and they categorized them in multiple zone i.e North America, South America.

While on other hand office property get the address of the location.

Comment: this is as good as any.  But really  - you can use the property however it makes sense for your organization. I've seen those used to cover things like building or seat assignments as well.

Comment: On my last job we used this, as i mentioned the same way but our terms are more state specfic.

Comment: Where can you setup this termset ?